# Why is QPushButton one pixel smaller than other widgets?

Tags: qt, qt5

I noticed that in the default Qt style, the push button is smaller than other widgets by one pixel at each side ([example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VtR5.png)). I wonder what the reason for this is. Is it supposed to be like this, or is it a bug?

I attempted to fix it using stylesheet:

```
QPushButton
{
  margin:-1px;

  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 6px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}
```

This seems to work fine on Windows 10 but results in ugly buttons on other versions. Which I solved by loading that stylesheet only when the program runs on Windows 10

```
if (QSysInfo::productVersion() == "10")
  // Set that stylesheet
```

Is this the correct way of solving the problem with QPushButton, or is there some cleaner way to fix (or work-around) this?

Answer (score 0):

autoDefault : bool

This property holds when the push button is an auto default button
It's so that when the autoDefault() is set to True an outline shows (warns) you that if you hit the 'Enter' key, this button is effectively pushed. From the docs:

If this property is set to true then the push button is an auto default button.

In some GUI styles a default button is drawn with an extra frame around it, up to 3 pixels or more. Qt automatically keeps this space free around auto-default buttons, i.e., auto-default buttons may have a slightly larger size hint.

This property's default is true for buttons that have a QDialog parent; otherwise it defaults to false.